# Problem accessing wcf data service inside class library referenced by my web app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, wcf-data-services

Getting resource error when accessing a cloud data service through a vb.net class from my Web App.

I have written a vb.net class library (call it MYAPPIF) referencing a wcf data service with common functions that work on these. For example I may want to save a transaction, I will do it through this class library. This class library is then referenced by my web app and with "Imports MYAPPIF" I can see the common functions and I can see the cloud service reference.

```
    dim oMyAppIF = new MyAppIF.class
    dim oCloudContext = oMyAppIF.GetWCFConnection()  ' a function in class
    oQueryList = (From seldata In oCloudContext.vwContractList
                  Order By seldata.cnname
                  Select seldata).ToList()
```

The web site compiles fine but when I run it I get the following error :

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: Resource not found for the segment 'vwContractList'.

Stack Trace:

[DataServiceClientException: Resource not found for the segment 'vwContractList'.]
   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery() +487
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +186

Comment: What is `oCloudContext.vwContractList`...

Comment: oCloudContext is an object reference to the wcf data service and vwContractList is an entityframework object

Answer (score 1):

Do not invoke the service by adding a service reference in the class library project, because the class library will use the WebConfig file of the current Web APP project instead of the configuration of the class library. You can copy the configuration under servicemodel into the current project, or use the channel factory call to write the configuration dynamically.

```
public string Invocation()
        {
            //ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            //return client.GetData(34);
            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://10.157.18.36:12000/service1.svc"));
            IService1 sv = factory.CreateChannel();
            return sv.GetData(46);
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So instead of invoking the oCloudConext inside my class library I do it in my web app and then pass the reference to my various functions inside my class library, that works and fixes the issue, but, are you suggesting I can create oCloudContext inside my class library by using the special channelFactory function you mention above ?

Comment: Yes, this way to call the service is able to configure these parameters programmatically instead of the configration file.